# Apache doesn't start on any port

Tags: apache, server, port

I just installed apache 2.2 and it was working just fine after I restarted that this error appears when I'm trying to start that:

```
The requested operation has failed!
```

first I thought It's about the default 80 port that apache is using so I turned off IIL from windows features but that didn't help
so I change the port from Apache httpd.conf
but still this error prevents me from starting the server.
does anyone know how can I fix this?
any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed apache 2.2.9 instead of 2.2.11 and it's working fine